# vCenter Converter - migrate P2V without dedicated boot partition

Tags: virtual-machine, vcenter, p2v

I'm looking to migrate a physical machine to my ESXi cluster with vCenter Converter but actually I got this following error :

> There is no '/boot' directory mounted on the source machine. It is required to create a bootable virtual machine. Mount the '/boot' directory on the source machine.

Is it possible to ignore this message ?
Actually this server is in production and I don't have any space left on my hard drive to create another partition.

**I would like to know if we can convert a physical machine to a VM without a dedicated /boot partition.**

Note: I got a /boot folder but mounted on my /

If someone got any advice about this will be helpfull :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so vmware answered me about this error message and it seems vCenter Converter doesn't support raid software :(

Too bad.

Source : https://communities.vmware.com/message/2439863#2439863

Comment: So what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with VMware Converter v6.0, then I upgraded to v6.2 and it worked!  Apparently the newer version supports the software raid.